# C how to find the repeated digit

Tags: c

How to find the repeated digit and export it ,

Enter your number :  226644
         the repeated digit : 2 6 4

I tried to solve this program but I failured.I have post my coding， Thanks for your help !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int main(){
    int  i, j, n ;
    int  a[10], m = 10;
    bool b[10] = {false};
    printf("Enter your digit:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(n > 0){
        j = n % 10;
        if(b[j] ){
            printf("The repeated digit is:");
            if( m != j){
                m = j;
                printf("%3d", m);
            }
            b[j] = true;
            n /= 10;
        }
    }   

    if(m == 10){
        printf("There is no repeated digit!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve and what goes wrong!

Comment: `bool b[10] = {false};` will only initialise the zeroth element. The rest will not be. Undefined behaviour time.

Comment: Do you want to write something about expected behavior, test cases, ...

Comment: You have wrong title - you are looking for repeated digit, not number! I need some time to understand the question with this err.

Comment: I am looking for the reapted digit, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Move `n /= 10;` one level up - in the `while` loop and not in sub-`if`. Now you have infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to i486's correction, also the line

```
            b[j] = true;
```

has to be moved out of (after) the `if(b[j] ){…}` block; otherwise no `b[j]` ever becomes `true`.